# can not install package afex because dependency ‘pbkrtest’ is not available (R version is 4.0 )

Tags: r, macos, cran

This is the console output:

```
> install.packages("afex")
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘pbkrtest’ is not available
also installing the dependency ‘car’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
     binary source needs_compilation
car  3.0-12  3.1-2             FALSE
afex  1.1-0  1.3-0             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘car’, ‘afex’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/car_3.1-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 579829 bytes (566 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 566 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/afex_1.3-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3567552 bytes (3.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.4 MB

ERROR: dependency ‘pbkrtest’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/car’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘car’ are not available for package ‘afex’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/afex’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘afex’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/7c/q8kd6bqj44z_qb7ld8bf4pn40000gn/T/RtmpkD93vM/downloaded_packages’
>
```

I use R framework 4.0. and RStudio on Mac.
I also tried the command:
`install.packages("afex", dependencies = TRUE)`
It did not work either.

I am a beginner in R, please help me.

Comment: Current version of [`pbkrtest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html) needs R (≥ 4.1.0) . Either try and install an older version of `pbkrtest` .. but better to upgrade your R version

Comment: also [afex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/index.html) has a lot of dependencies some of which need R ≥ 4.1.0 ... so def easier to upgrade your R version